# Wolfram|Alpha Python API not working on MacOS Sierra

Tags: python, macos-sierra, wolframalpha

I'm using Python 3.6 on MacOS Sierra 10.12.3. I installed `wolframalpha`, and made sure my app id is valid (it works fine with URL requests using RESTful), yet I still get this error when I try and run the example from Wolfram's own documentation:

```
import wolframalpha

client = wolframalpha.Client('xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx')

res = client.query('temperature in Washington, DC on October 3, 2012')
```

Gives me these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1318, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1400, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 401, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 808, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1061, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 683, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Zachary/OneDrive/Python/Enthio copy.py", line 5, in <module>
    res = client.query('temperature in Washington, DC on October 3, 2012')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wolframalpha/__init__.py", line 53, in query
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1361, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1320, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)>
```

Any ideas? I don't know what to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wolfram Alpha Python: SSL: CERTIFICATE\_VERIFY\_FAILED error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55189120/wolfram-alpha-python-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error)

Answer (score 0):

> ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify
>   failed

indicates that you have to do `import ssl` also.

Comment: Thanks, I tried doing that to no avail. That message, as well as the others, still persists.