# Wolfram Alpha Python: SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error

Tags: python, wolframalpha

I have been trying to run this simple code snippet to check my installation of Wolfram Alpha on Python.

This is the code I have been trying to run:

```
import ssl
import wolframalpha
app_id = "*****************"
client = wolframalpha.Client(app_id)
my_input = input("Question: ")
res = client.query(my_input)
answer = next(res.results).text 
print(answer)
```

This is the error I have been facing

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MARIA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1318, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "C:\Users\MARIA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\MARIA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\MARIA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\MARIA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\MARIA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\MARIA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1400, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\MARIA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\ssl.py", line 407, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "C:\Users\MARIA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\ssl.py", line 817, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\MARIA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1077, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\MARIA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:847)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\MARIA\TEST_walpha.py", line 6, in <module>
    res = client.query(my_input)
  File "C:\Users\MARIA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\wolframalpha\__init__.py", line 53, in query
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  File "C:\Users\MARIA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\MARIA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Users\MARIA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Users\MARIA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\MARIA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1361, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\MARIA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1320, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:847)>
```

Now I consulted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42503462/wolfram-alpha-python-api-not-working) post, but there was no clear answer provide, and importing the SSL library did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try disabling certificate verification globally by doing something like this:

```
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

Comment: the program ran perfectly. You sir, are a lifesaver. Thank you so much!

Comment: Note that this _disables certificate validation completely_, which is a potential security risk. A proper solution would involve modification of the library's code. You may want to reach out to those who maintain the library and ask if they could do something about that.

Comment: i realise that it is bad practice. I read about it online, and everywhere it is advised to not disable the security verification, but since I have a project demonstration tomorrow, I am looking to patch my code up for demo purposes only. Once it is done, I will have some time on my hand to identify the source of the problem, and fix it. I will be sure to contact the maintainers about the issue.